# How to put lists together into json in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I have this code here in C# (just a sample):

```
var list1 = ( from x
    join y
    select new
    {
        id, name
    });

var counta = list1.count;
if (counta > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < counta; i++)
    {
        var userid = list1[i].id;
        var user = user.Where(a => a.id == user).Select(a => a.userid).FirstOrDefault();
        var list2 = (
            from f
            join g.Where(a => a.userid = user)select new
            {
            hourId, hourName
            }
        );
        if (list2 > 0)
        {
            foreach (var product in list2)
            {
                var list3 = (
                    from p.
                    where (a => a.id == user)join q.
                    where (a => a.id == user)select new
                    {
                    productId, productName
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is list1,list2,list3 relationship: list1 has many list2, list2 has many list3 and here is the JSON that I expected to return:

```
[
  {
    "list1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Adam",
      "list2": [
        {
          "hourId": 1,
          "hourName": "08:00",
          "list3": [
            {
              "productId": 1,
              "productName": "Candy"
            },
            {
              "productId": 2,
              "productName": "Cookie"
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          "hourId": 2,
          "hourName": "09:00",
          "list3": [
            {
              "productId": 1,
              "productName": "Candy"
            },
            {
              "productId": 2,
              "productName": "Cookie"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

So my question here is how can I put list1, list2, list3 together to return the below JSON? Do I have to join 3 lists in LINQ again?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using dynamic types, you should create proper classes with properties and create instances of them and populate them and then use JSON serializer to create the JSON you want.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and modify the code so that it can be compiled, run and tested -- i.e. a [mcve]?  You write *here is the JSON that I expected to return:* but we have no way of knowing what is currently returned how how to reproduce your problem.